# Jingle video stream in a web browser

Tags: video, applet, web, libjingle

I'm looking at moving my live video streaming solution from the open source Red5 server to a P2P solution using XMPP/Jingle.

I have a modified version of the libJingle "call" application that provides live video streaming between 2 instances of the application, but I really need the receiver to be embedded in a browser. To do this, I've been looking at writing a Java Applet and started looking at the Smack API and smackx-jingle, but it looks like the Jingle project isn't complete and has been abandoned.

I'm wondering are there any other real options for having a client that can do the XMPP/Jingle communication and display the video feed in a web browser?

My current options are wrapping libJingle in JNI which is going to be a huge task and I'd rather avoid if possible, or implementing the Jingle extension myself on top of the Smack API.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or direction.

Regards,

Phil

Comment: from where we get modified version of libjingle call application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using WebRTC? http://www.webrtc.org

Comment: I had looked at WebRTC, but my understanding is that it currently has limited browser support. From what I've read about it, Chrome supports it quite well (as Google are developing it), Firefox is starting to catch up, but Microsoft have only just started looking at it in April 2012.
The project I'm working on is for production so really needs to be as accessible as possible across all platform / browser configurations (excluding mobile)